# Issue exporting bash shell output to text file

Tags: bash, shell

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1. date
date
echo -e "\n"
echo 2. hostname
hostname
echo -e "\n"
echo 3. arch
arch
echo -e "\n"
echo 4. uname -a
uname -a
echo -e "\n"
echo 5.uptime
uptime
echo -e "\n"
echo 6. whoami
whoami
echo -e "\n"
echo 7. who
who
echo -e "\n"
echo 8. last
last
echo -e "\n"
echo 9. finger
finger
echo -e "\n"
echo 10. w
w
echo -e "\n"
echo 11. top
top -n 1
echo -e "\n"
echo 12. history
tail -100 ${HOME}/.bash_history
echo -e "\n"
echo End of Script!
```

when I run it works fine and displays all the code on screen, however when I save to txt file using ./keithbrazill.sh > keithbrazill.txt, it does not show all the text output and only part output. Any advice? I tried a few different variations of output command such as &>, >> etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to reproduce the problem:

```
echo "Hello"; whoami     # Shows output from both commands
echo "World"; top -n 1   # Shows output only from top
```

This happens because `top` is a ncurses program that outputs terminal control sequences to draw itself fullscreen, overwriting anything already on screen. While all the data does end up in the file, it'll show a lot of gibberish in a text editor, and if you `cat` it, the terminal sequences will overwrite the output of other commands.

You can use `top -b -n 1` to instead get plaintext output.

Comment: Thanks fpr your comment I tried this but it is still only displaying a limited amount of text on my text file I basically only see what will fit on one screen...

Comment: How are you viewing the file?